# Is it possible to remove the red underscoring of "Drupal" 

Tags: support

It'll be better if the word Drupal doesn't get an ugly highlight from the spell checker (at least in this website). I was wondering if it was possible.

Comment: It's a browser specific issue. just right click on Drupal in a text box, and then choose "Add to Dictionary."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't depend from the site, but from the browser you are using, which is checking the words you are writing, and underlining in red the words it doesn't find in the dictionary file it uses. As Drupal it's not an English word, the browser reports it is wrong. As Jin says, if you say to the browser to add the word to the dictionary file, it will not report that word as wrong.

With Safari, you select "Learn Spelling."

[image: screenshot]

(As I have already forced the browser to add "Drupal" to its dictionary, I had to show what happens with another word, and I chose "Joomla.")